# Hiding Url for asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, iframe, url-rewriting

I'm creating an html page that is posted to another page for processing. I don't want users to see the weird URL they are redirected to and I was using FRAMES but I can't figure out how to add my HTML page dynamically because I need the variables and either add frames or try another way to accomplish this. So, based on how I'm creating the page below, how can I hide the URL and add something that I want.

Here is how I'm creating the page.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<html><head></head>");
    sb.Append("<body onload=\"document.frmLaunch.submit();\">");
    sb.Append("<form name=\"frmLaunch\" action=\"" + variableTargetURL + "\" method=\"post\">");
    sb.Append("<input type=hidden name=\"testVariable\" value=\"" + variableTest + "\">");
    sb.Append("</form>");
    sb.Append("</body></html>");
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.Write(sb.ToString()); response.End();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing the redirect on the server, [`Server.Transfer`](http://dotnetperls.com/server-transfer-use-aspnet) will not update the URL in the browser on the client.

Answer (score 0):

You have url rewriting as a tag - is setting up your web.config and using [asp.net url rewriting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx) (as you are using asp.net and C#) the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If this is ASP.Net 3.5 or later try [ASP.Net Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx).  It's not just for MVC applications.

Otherwise, checkout your list of options in the article [Tip/Trick: Url Rewriting with ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx).

The heart of most of the rewrite engines out there is the [HttpContext.RewritePath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa5wkk6d.aspx) method.  I've used this method directly in [HttpApplication_BeginRequest()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest.aspx) and it works well on it's own.  So you can take that approach as well.

Answer (score 0):

I went with just creating the page inside the frame.